# I can't iterate over UploadTask in addOnSuccessListener

Tags: android, kotlin, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I get the following error when trying to iterate over the uploadTasks inside an addOnSuccessListener method.

> java.lang.ClassCastException: com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask$TaskSnapshot cannot be cast to com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask

So how can i get the Download String of each Img inside addOnSuccessListener?

```
val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
val tasks = mutableListOf<UploadTask>()

listImg.forEach {
        if(bitmap!!.byteCount != it.byteCount) {
            val bitmap = it
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
            val data = baos.toByteArray()
            var uploadTask = spaceRef.putBytes(data)

            tasks.add(uploadTask)
        }
    }


Tasks.whenAllSuccess<UploadTask>(tasks).addOnSuccessListener { uploadTasks ->
        //uploadTasks has size of 2
        val urls = mutableListOf<Uri>()
        
        lifecycleScope.launch
        {
            //Error throws here
            uploadTasks.forEach{

            urls.add(it.await().storage.downloadUrl.await())
        }

     }
 }
```

Comment: How is your `tasks` initialized?

Comment: Hi "Frank" @Frank van Puffelen This is how I initialized the tasks ---> val tasks = mutableListOf<UploadTask>()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The type of `whenAllSuccess` is `<TResult>`, so you should use the result type of `UploadTask` (`UploadTask.TaskSnapshot`) instead:

```kotlin
Tasks.whenAllSuccess<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>(tasks).addOnSuccessListener { uploadTasks ->
```

And then you can drop the the first `await()` on that last line:

```kotlin
urls.add(it.storage.downloadUrl.await())
```

##### Bonus: Don't block the main thread

Note that `Tasks.whenAllSuccess()` will block the main thread until all uploads succeed, meaning your UI might freeze while uploading files.
To avoid that, consider uploading your files with Coroutines:

```kotlin
val baos = ByteArrayOutputStream()
val urls = mutableListOf<Uri>()

lifecycleScope.launch {
    listImg.forEach {
        if(bitmap!!.byteCount != it.byteCount) {
            val bitmap = it
            bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos)
            val data = baos.toByteArray()

            // Upload the image first
            val taskSnapshot = spaceRef.putBytes(data).await()
            // Get the download Url
            val downloadUri = taskSnapshot.storage.downloadUrl.await()
            // Add it to the list of Uris
            urls.add(downloadUri)
        }
    }
}
```